# Probability proportion question

Tags: probability, statistics

> Given a choice between Brand A and Brand B of a brand of jeans, $75$% of women will choose brand A. If an SRS of $50$ women is taken, the probability that the sample proportion of those who would choose brand A is less than $0.65$ is closest to

I am not sure how to solve this, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $\text{Prob}(\hat{p} < 0.65)=\text{Prob}\left(\dfrac{\hat{p} - p}{\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}}<\dfrac{0.65-.75}{\sqrt{\frac{0.75\cdot 0.25}{50}}}\right)=...$

Comment: do we use the Z table so thus we compute P(Z < -1.634)?

Comment: You sure do.....

Comment: Yes, difference of proportions is normally-distributed.